# tfs build svn does not trigger on checkin

Tags: svn, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a svn project and want to use continuous integration. For now, I have followed the Tutorial on the MSDN website. Can anybody tell me, why the build is still not triggering? The build is running when I am queueing it manually.
Also I would like to know if the build is running with sl2016/2016_2_x instead of 2016_x when there is a checkin in that path.

My configuration:

[image: Repository]

[image: CI]
The filters say include.

Comment: The "Polling interval" is configured to "60" seconds, can you wait for 60 seconds to see if the build is triggered?

Comment: there are about 3 checkins per hour and no build is running after an hour now

Answer (score 0):

The value of ***Default branch or tag*** represent you are going to build a default branch (or tag) in your Subversion repository with this build definition.

Checking in code in sl2016/2016_2_x will not trigger the build. Since you are not building the branch.

You can set the default branch or tag = `sl2016` and try again.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to remove that in `standardbranch` for the picture. It only was a desperate try previously. I already knew that but the build actually does not trigger even when it is set to default `sl2016/2016_x` and the filter only looks for `sl2016/2016_x`.

Comment: What's the result if you check "Batch changes"   on the setting page of trigger?

Comment: Try to create a new build definition with some settings and try again. Check in not trigger the build also occurs on some gated check-in build. The way above did the trick.